# Use rebase when Sync in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, git-rebase

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Git. When I need to push my commits I use fetch and rebase to merge the new commits before push. This is my company default policy to mantain the history clear without the join merges.

Is possible to configure the Sync feature of Visual Studio 2015 Team Explorer to use rebase when pull? In the Git config is possible set the pull to use rebase instead merge by default, but Visual Studio Sync seems to use another configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of right now, it looks like this feature isn't supported by Visual Studio.

You can see the references [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10294356-sync-button-should-allow-git-pull-rebase) and [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/4902965-allow-git-tools-for-visual-studio-to-rebase-on-pul).

> ... For now Visual Studio does a `git pull --no-rebase` when clicking on `pull`. 
>   Visual Studio should just do a `git pull`, 
>   therefore allowing the user to choose the behavior through the console...

As seen in the above quote, VS is explicitly stating that a sync is run with the `--no-rebase` option. The suggested comments on those pages that it should use the global configuration settings is incorrect because of this explicit option being present.

You are limited to manually doing rebases at the moment.

Comment: Update: that feature is currently being developed by Microsoft

Comment: @dialex any reference?

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.28 you can run rebase with sync:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_always-rebase-when-running-sync